# Instructions Installing Juno Pulse

Tags: system-installation, java, jupiter

I need to install Juno Pulse - how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full Explination how to Install Juno Pulse and connect to remote access:

http://computing.vt.edu/kb/entry/3987

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi that worked although I seen that web page prior to you sending I went ack and saw some beginer mistakes I had made and agin thank you. Now, all I have to do is figure out why PIDGIN for work doesn't work.

Comment: Well done. You are welcome!

Comment: Link is no longer live.