# Does junos pulse work for ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

I want to use junos pulse for Ubuntu 14.04.

Does junos pulse work for ubuntu?

if no, is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instructions Installing Juno Pulse](http://askubuntu.com/questions/555092/instructions-installing-juno-pulse)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's available.
Pleas refer to [How do I download and install Junos Pulse in Linux? How do I connect to the remote access - VPN in Linux?](https://vt4help.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0010398)
to learn how to get it.

Steps are:

- Verify your status, and install Java JRE.
- Log on to the Web page with your credentials.
- Download and save the ncLinuxApp.jar file to your computer.
- When the download is complete, unpackage the ncLinuxApp.jar file.
- Download and save the SSL certificate.
- Export the new PATH
- send only VT traffic through the VPN or all traffic through the VPN

---

Two possible alternatives are:

1. [Cisco AnyConnect](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/index.html)
2. [Stonesoft MobileID](http://alternativeto.net/software/stonesoft/)