# JRE not installed/Java is disabled on Ubuntu 14 but works on another distro

Tags: 14.04, java, openjdk, jre

I need to run some js from a webpage, but when it tries to load I got the error of the subject topic. I'm running ubuntu 14, FF 50xx, and latest version of java.

But, that part of the page that came from a .cgi works on FF 41, mint 14xx and:

> java version "1.7.0_79"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
>   OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

I ran FF 41xx and didn't work. I download the exact same version of java:
**openjdk-7-source_7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1_all.deb**

Purged everything else :
**apt-get purge openjdk-* icedtea-* icedtea6-***

And then I installed the 7u79xx with gdebi, but instead I got the:

> java version "1.7.0_121"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.8) (7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.14.04.1)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.121-b00, mixed mode)

Even when I manually removed the deb packages of 7u121xx version, I guess that aptitude looked up for newer versions and downloaded them. Anyhow, this didn't work either.

I read another article about it, but I don't have some files that requires java to run on /usr/bin (speaking of extracting the files from a *.tar.gz).

I'll try now to install the 7u79xx package without updating the package to the 7u121.

I appreciate it if someone can give me a hand on how to make this run. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To future readers, this worked that time on: 64 bits Xenial / FF 47 and 32 bits Xenial / FF 51, quite old now but could give you a hint on the how to:

Install specific java version:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk:i386
```

If you don't have the repos, do:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa  
apt-get update
```

Choose which java to use:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java):

```
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java    1070      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

*Noticed that I checked option 2: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java

Install FF icedtea plugins:

```
apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Worked on my default FF 50.1.0 BUT, now it says:

> setup failed please install 32 bit java and update...etc.

So, I got to this article : [How to install Juniper VPN on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450369/how-to-install-juniper-vpn-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

-

I'm now using:

> java version "1.7.0_79"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

**update-alternatives --config java**

loading java from: **1 /opt/jdk/jre1.7.0_79/bin/java 100 manual**

Then,

I realiaze that I didn't have a FF java plugin going trough a FF tab and -> **about:plugins**

-

So, after reading this: [How to install the Java plugin for Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354361/how-to-install-the-java-plugin-for-firefox/354406)

I did this:

**apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin**

The result (FF tab -> about:plugins) :

IcedTea-Web Plugin (using IcedTea-Web 1.5.3 (1.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1))

```
File: IcedTeaPlugin.so
Path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
Version: 
State: Enabled
The IcedTea-Web Plugin executes Java applets.
```

-

I'll try now the first article that I've mentioned on the beginning of this post and I'll post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing turned out to be that the juniper VPN client don't get along with 64 bits systems, so, there is a bunch of documentation, scripts, etc.

Such as: 
[How to install Juniper VPN on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450369/how-to-install-juniper-vpn-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

http://mad-scientist.us/juniper.html

[Juniper Network Connect not working on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778594/juniper-network-connect-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Since I was about to already reinstall my OS, I'll decide to go for a 32 bit OS, I'll use it only for work, so it's okay. I don't want to have plenty of both 32/64 versions of FF, JAVA, plugins, etc. Since I would had to do that in order to get this run properly.